# Ways to say 'try very hard'

Tags: single-word-requests

I was wondering what some ways are to say one tries very hard.

For example, can I say

> I gave myself (all) out last year.

Comment: Your example sounds awkward.  "I gave my all last year", or "I went all out last year" sound more natural.

Comment: With or without "all", I think the example is poor English. The closest *valid* related form I can think of is **I gave [it] my all last year**.

Comment: Are there ways to make questions like this "community wiki" like you can on stackoverflow? I don't see how this question could possibly have a single right answer.

Comment: How is this a single word request?

Comment: I voted to close because I feel this question is overly broad.  I think this question could be improved if you either asked specifically how to use the phrase you have given, or requested an idiomatic phrase for "try very hard" that could not be found in a thesaurus.

Answer (score 2):

WE could say:

> He put in a lot of effort.
>   He gave it all he had
>   He did his very best.
>   He put in a Herculean effort.

Comment: Thanks! How about the example in my post?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense too.